# Find all pairs of naturals $(a,b)$ such that $a^b-b^a=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This question is given in AMTI second level contest.

> Find all pairs of naturals $(a,b)$ such that $a^b-b^a=3$.

**My try**: One such pair is $(4,1)$. Are there any other pairs? Please help me.

Comment: consider $f(x)=x^b-b^x-3$ and use dervative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking mod 2 we can easily see that exactly one of them is even .
Case 1. $a=2m$:
$$(2m)^b-b^{2m}=3$$

 If $b\geq3$, $(2m)^b\equiv 0\pmod 8$ so
$$-b^{2m}\equiv 3\pmod 8$$
$$b^{2m}\equiv 5\pmod 8$$
 but no square is 5 mod 8,so no solution, so $b=1$
$$2m-1=3$$ $$m=2,a=4$$
Case 1. $b=2m$:
 
$$(a)^{2m}-(2m)^{a}=3$$

 If $a\geq3$, $(2m)^a\equiv 0\pmod 8$ so
$$a^{2m}\equiv 3\pmod 8$$ but no square is 3 mod 8,so no solution, so $a=1$
$$1-2m=3$$ but no natural solution

The only solution is $(4,1)$

Comment: Should use $\ge$ (dollar sign, \ge, dollar sign) instead of >.

Comment: @OscarLanzi yeah now I'll edit, thank you.